# A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Space>'

Tags: flutter, dart

A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.

and error in List data = snapshot.data;

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: spaceProvider.getRecomendedSpace(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<Space> data = snapshot.data;
                  return Column(
                      children:
                          data.map((item) => SpaceCard(item)).toList());
                }
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: replace var with List<Space>

Comment: Please mark this question as answered if you got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

add type to the`FutureBuilder` widget, like this:

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
            child: FutureBuilder<List<Space>>( // here
              future: spaceProvider.getRecomendedSpace(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<Space> data = snapshot.data;
                  return Column(
                      children:
                          data.map((item) => SpaceCard(item)).toList());
                }
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

note that the function `spaceProvider.getRecomendedSpace()` must return a `List<Space>`

Comment: No, `spaceProvider.getRecomendedSpace()` must return an instance of `Future<List<Space>>`.

Comment: yes that's correct, future parameter must take a `Future` that's why i didn't mention it

Answer (score 1):

When calling a `future` inside **FutureBuilder** whatever we `return` from the `future` function moves to `snapshot` and by default type of snapshot is `object` so whenever you want to receive data in same type that you are `returning`, you have to tell `snapshot` it's `type`. by using `AsyncSnapshot`.

```
AsyncSnapshot<Type>
```

See Example below

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: spaceProvider.getRecomendedSpace(),
              builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List<Space>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<Space> data = snapshot.data;
                  return Column(
                      children:
                          data.map((item) => SpaceCard(item)).toList());
                }
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```